# Private module method accessible by module classes

Tags: ruby, oop, rubygems

I'm trying to wrap the functionality of a command-line utility (let's call it `foo`) with a Ruby gem. I'm trying to abstract out some of the functionality into different classes, but I'd like to have the logic which deals with calling out to the system in one method so that I can handle errors from the application in a single place.

I can easily do this by defining a method in the main module of the gem

```
module Foo
  def self.execute(*args)
    exec('foo', *args)
    # Pretend there is a lot more error handling etc. here
  end
end
```

And then each of the classes can shuttle calls to the executable via this method

```
module Foo
  class Bar

    # Access via class method
    def self.list_bars
      Foo.execute('ls', 'bars')
    end

    # Access via instance method
    def initialize
      # Make a call to the system executable via the class method
      Foo.execute('initialize', 'bar')
    end

    def config(*args)
      Foo.execute('config', 'bar', *args)
    end
  end
end
```

Ideally, though, I'd like to make the `Foo.execute` method *private* so that the public API of my module is solely the abstractions of `foo`. If I mark `Foo.execute` as `private` though, then the other classes in the module (obviously) can't access it.

How can this be accomplished succinctly with Ruby 2.3?

It's also worth noting that I'm really only using the module `Foo` for namespacing purposes.

Comment: `private` and `protected` work better in a class environment. Modules don't inherit in the same way so the restrictions are a lot more strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules in ruby are just containers for methods and constants. Classes know nothing about the modules that they form part of and don't inherit from them. so there is no way to make a method on ´Foo´ available for all the classes that may be inside it.

This approach may give you what you want.

```
module Foo
  module CommandRunning
    def execute(*args)
      # ...
    end
  end

  class Bar
    include CommandRunning

    def initialize
      execute('initialize', 'bar')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This was very helpful. I ended up doing something very similar. Thanks!